# Only show Sorting option not filtering opetion in contex menu of header in ListViewByQuery

Tags: development, list, filter, sorting

I have creatd ListViewByQuery control through coding and added the control through RencerControl Event.

I am filtering the list in code. so filtered result is shown. I want to hide filter context menu as i dont want to show other value of filtered column. But i want to show sorting functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried setting the DisableFilter property to true?

Comment: +1. In addition, link to DisableFilter property description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery.disablefilter.aspx